# XAMPP PDO Oracle, Cant make it work together

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

i want to make connection of PDO to oracle database.

i tried all day to set it up, i am using xampp, installed latest version of xampp.

i tried to follow this guide: [Installing PHP and the Oracle Instant Client for Linux and Windows](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/technote-php-instant-12c-2088811.html)

Also have tried to follow this guide: [Activate Oracle on XAMPP for Windows : OCI8](http://jaswanttak.wordpress.com/2010/08/31/activate-oracle-on-xampp-for-windows-oci8/)

Please anyone help me guide me to the right direction. I am stucked and it is a must to do job, cuz all my work relies on it.

the server i want to deploy my file, runs on oracle database, thats why i want to tryout the oracle in my local PC.